# Determining the sender of WM_SYSCOMMAND with LParam 0 in Delphi VCL forms

Tags: delphi, access-violation, vcl

## The problem

When running an application written in C, that uses some dll's written in Delphi XE7, I run into an access violation in the following code, which is in the vcl.forms.pas of the vcl library.

```
procedure TCustomForm.CMAppSysCommand(var Message: TMessage);
{$IF NOT DEFINED(CLR)}
type
  PWMSysCommand = ^TWMSysCommand;
{$ENDIF}
begin
  Message.Result := 0;
  if (csDesigning in ComponentState) or (FormStyle = fsMDIChild) or
   (Menu = nil) or Menu.AutoMerge then
{$IF DEFINED(CLR)}
    with TWMSysCommand.Create(Message) do
{$ELSE}
    with PWMSysCommand(Message.lParam)^ do
{$ENDIF}
    begin
      SendCancelMode(nil);
      if SendAppMessage(CM_APPSYSCOMMAND, CmdType, Key) <> 0 then   //Here the debugger shows the access violation
        Message.Result := 1;
    end;
end;
```

The access violation occurs on the line with SendAppMessage, and seems to be caused by the fact that the Message.LParam is 0. The message is a WM_SYSCOMMAND message. Is there a way to track where this message originated? In the call stack, all functions are part of the VCL or system files.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910991/how-can-my-app-find-the-sender-of-a-windows-message) suggest that in general it is **hard** to trace the sender of a windows message. However, since in my case everything is within the same application, I hope that might make it easier.

## What have I tried?

### Overruling the vcl source

Previously, this same bug appeared in the forms.pas and was fixed by adding a copy of that file to the project and then checking that LParam <> 0 in this function.
I have tried doing the same thing with the vcl.forms.pas that is now used, but this leads to compilation errors. Even with answers as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10470943/how-to-recompile-modifications-to-vcl-source-file-menus-pas) I was not able to build it. However, many google hits also suggested that it is in general a bad idea to change things in the vcl, so I try to avoid that option.

### Other questions on StackOverFlow

[This article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37690519/delphi-tactionmainmenu-accelerators-on-secondary-form/37692023#37692023) gave me good information about the underlying system and how it might have occured that the Message.LParam is 0. However, I did not know how to find the source of the message or what class I should be looking for that generated it.

## The solution

As described in Remy's accepted answer below, the immediate problem could be solved by having the class provide a CMAppSysCommand function to guard against LParam = 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you describe should not be possible under normal conditions.

There are only two places in the entire VCL where `CM_APPSYSCOMMAND` is sent from:

1. `TWinControl.WMSysCommand()`, which is called when a UI control receives a `WM_SYSCOMMAND` message.  The `LParam` of the `CM_APPSYSCOMMAND` message is never set to 0, it is set to a pointer to the `TMessage` record of the original `WM_SYSCOMMAND` message:

   ```
   Form := GetParentForm(Self);
   if (Form <> nil) and
     (Form.Perform(CM_APPSYSCOMMAND, 0, Winapi.Windows.LPARAM(@Message)) <> 0) then
     Exit;
   ```
2. `TCustomForm.CMAppSysCommand()`, which is called when a Form receives a `CM_APPSYSCOMMAND` message. It forwards the message to the `TApplication` window (using `SendAppMessage()`, which just calls `SendMessage(Application.Handle, ...)` with the provided parameters):

   ```
   with PWMSysCommand(Message.lParam)^ do
   begin
     ...
     if SendAppMessage(CM_APPSYSCOMMAND, CmdType, Key) <> 0 then
       Message.Result := 1;
   end;
   ```

The [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37690519/) you mention explains how `CM_APPSYSCOMMAND` is used by the VCL, but does not say anything that would suggest how its `LParam` could ever be 0 in `TCustomForm.CMAppSysCommand()`, because it can't ever be 0 under normal circumstances.  It can be 0 in `TApplication.WndProc()`, but that is perfectly OK.

The only possibility I can think of would be if someone is manually sending a fake `CM_APPSYSCOMMAND` message (which is `CM_BASE + 23 = $B017`, aka `WM_APP + $3017`) directly to your `TForm` window.  Only `TWinControl` should ever be doing that.  And since `TWinControl` uses `Perform()` instead of `SendMessage()` for that send, you should be seeing `TWinControl.WMSysCommand()` on the call stack of `TCustomForm.CMAppSysCommand()`.  If you do not, then the message is fake.  And if it is being sent using `SendMessage()` instead of `Perform()`, there is no way to know where the message is coming from.

However, in any case, this is very easy to guard against, without altering any VCL source code.  Simply have your DLL's `TForm` class provide its own message handler for `CM_APPSYSCOMMAND`, either using the `message` directive, or by overriding the virtual `WndProc()` method.  Either way, you can discard the message if the `LParam` is 0, eg:

```
type
  TMyForm = class(TForm)
  ...
  private
    procedure CMAppSysCommand(var Message: TMessage); message CM_APPSYSCOMMAND;
  ...
  end;

procedure TMyForm.CMAppSysCommand(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  if Message.LParam = 0 then
    Message.Result := 0
  else
    inherited;
end;
```

```
type
  TMyForm = class(TForm)
  ...
  protected
    procedure WndProc(var Message: TMessage); override;
  ...
  end;

procedure TMyForm.WndProc(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  if (Message.Msg = CM_APPSYSCOMMAND) and (Message.LParam = 0) then
    Message.Result := 0
  else
    inherited;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer! I was not able to track down where the message originated from, but having the class provide it's own message handler solved the issue.